# Find path of applicaiton installed Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, pycharm, shortcut-file

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=PyCharm Community Edition
Icon=pycharm-community
Exec=pycharm-community %f
Comment=Develop with pleasure!
Categories=Development;IDE;
Terminal=false
StartupWMClass=jetbrains-pycharm-ce
```

I know the format of a desktop entry file but I'm trying to find out where the application has been installed. This desktop entry shows in the search and on clicking it PyCharm opens as it is supposed to.

Also I did not understand what %f stands for from the [Documentation](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/ar01s06.html)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can always try running "which pycharm-community" in your terminal, it will probably output a path of the binary it is trying to start.

Comment: if you press the check mark under this answer, you can flag this question as answered!

Answer (score 5):

you can try locate function:

```
locate * | grep "name_you_look_for"
```

Answer (score 4):

you can try to find the pycharm.sh file as,

```
sudo find / -iname pycharm.sh
```

for me, it was located at path :

```
/home/<username>/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/PyCharm-C/ch-0/201.7223.92/bin/pycharm.sh
```